Sass: How to replace @import with @use
I have a file _tumblelog.scss with the following:
body {
    background-color: $background-color;
}

It's designed to provide the main CSS structure for several themes. In a theme SCSS file I do the following, for example:
$background-color: #0a0a0a;

@import 'tumblelog';

How do I rewrite this to avoid the deprecated @import?
Edit
I currently have in _tumblelog.scss:
$background-color: null !default;

body { background-color: $background-color; }

and in the theme SCSS file:
@use 'tumblelog' with (
    $background-color: red
);

Is this the way to go?

Yes, that looks good I think.
